# Swift generic Serializable protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I noticed that I have a lot of repeated code for getting/sending JSON to my app's API, but the only thing that is different is what entity is being (de)serialized. So I came up with the following design (for brevity only the GET method):

HTTPClient.swift

```
func getEntityJSON<T: JSONSerializable>(
    type: T.Type,
    url: String,
    completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: T?,
                                  _ headers: [String: String]?,
                                  _ statusCode: Int?,
                                  _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    HttpClient.sharedInstance().getJSON(url, completionHandler: { (jsonData, headers, statusCode, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(nil, headers, statusCode, error)
        } else {
            if let entityData = jsonData {
                completionHandler(T.fromJSON(data: entityData), headers, statusCode, nil)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

to intend to use it like this:

```
HTTPClient.sharedInstance().getEntity(type: Translation, url: url) { (translation, _, _, _) in
    // do stuff with Translation instance
}
```

and here is the `JSONSerializable` protocol:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON


protocol Serializable: Codable {
    static func deserialize<T: Codable>(data: Data) -> T?
    func serialize() -> Data?
}

extension Serializable {
    static func deserialize<T: Decodable>(data: Data) -> T? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
        return try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
    
    func serialize() -> Data? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
        return try? encoder.encode(self)
    }
}

protocol JSONSerializable: Serializable {
    func toJSON() -> JSON?
    static func fromJSON<T>(data: JSON) -> T?
}


extension JSONSerializable {
    func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        if let data = self.serialize() {
            return try? JSON(data: data)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to define a struct like this:

Translation.swift

```
struct Translation: Hashable, Identifiable, JSONSerializable {
    var id: UUID
    ...
    
    static func fromJSON(data: JSON) -> Translation? {
```

and I will get `serialize, deserialize, toJSON` functions. But the compiler complains that `Translation` does not conform to `JSONSerializable`, due to lack of:

`static func fromJSON<T>(data: JSON) -> T?`. I thought I would be able to implement that function with a concrete type, `Translation` in this case.

I would like to be both able to do `Translations.fromJSON(data: data)` as well as `T.fromJSON(data: data)`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics (`<T>`) means that your method can work with any type that the *caller* (not the callee, not the implementer, not anyone else) specifies. In the case of `fromJSON`, this is clearly not the case. Any concrete implementation of `fromJSON` only works with `T` being the enclosing type, so `fromJSON` is not suitable to be generic.

When a method "only works with `T` being the enclosing type", it is the use case of `Self` types:

```
protocol JSONSerializable: Serializable {
    func toJSON() -> JSON?
    static func fromJSON(data: JSON) -> Self?
}
```

This way, your `Translation` implementation would conform to the protocol.

Similarly, `deserialise` should also be declared as:

```
static func deserialize(data: Data) -> Self?
```

If you actually want a `JSONSerialisable` that can turn `JSON` into any type that  the caller wants, then it's less of a `JSONSerialisable`, and more of a `JSONSerialiser`, and it doesn't make much sense to inherit from `Codable` in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer with the explanation and the suggestions on how to approach this. I guess it will take some time before I have a good understanding of generics.

Answer (score 0):

OK I ended up implementing a `JSONSerializer`, because I couldn't get it to work for collections of items to be (de)serialized. This is how it currently looks:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON


protocol JSONSerializable {
    static func fromJSON(data: JSON) -> Self?
}


class JSONSerializer {
    static func deserialize<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, data: Data) -> T? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
        return try? decoder.decode(type, from: data)
    }
    
    static func serialize<T: Encodable>(_ object: T) -> Data? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
        return try? encoder.encode(object)
    }
    
    static func fromJSON<T: JSONSerializable>(type: T.Type, data: JSON) -> T? {
        T.fromJSON(data: data)
    }
    
    static func toJSON<T: Encodable>(_ object: T) -> JSON? {
        if let data = Self.serialize(object) {
            return try? JSON(data: data)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I will look into the `fromJSON` function later to see if I can completely get rid of `JSONSerializable` and implemented it in the `JSONSerializer` like this:

```
    static func fromJSON<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type, data: JSON) -> T? {
        if let jsonData = try? data.rawData() {
            return Self.deserialize(type, data: jsonData)
        }
        return nil
    }
```